# How to escape the `@` variable replacement in `forfiles`?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd, escaping, forfiles

I am using a `forfiles` command line like this (Windows 7 x64):

```
forfiles /P "C:\root" /M "*.txt" /C "cmd /C echo @relpath"
```

How can I escape the replacement of `@relpath` (relative path to currently iterated item) to get `@relpath` output literally? (...or any other `@` variable?)

---

So far I tried the following things, without success:

- `\`: the `@` seems to be handled before `\` so `\@relpath` does not work, rather the expanded output is just preceded with `\`;
- `^`: stating `^@` does not show any effect except that the `^` disappears; writing `^^@` does not help eigher, one `^` remains in the expanded output then;
- `0xHH`: surprisingly (to me), the `forfiles`-specific replacement of hexacecimal numbers `0x40` does not work either, it seems that this is done prior to variable parsing;
- `@@`: doubling the `@` keeps the first `@` literally, that is it;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found an even easier method:

```
forfiles /P "C:\root" /M "*.txt" /C "cmd /C echo @^relpath"
```

Note the `^` *after* the `@` sign.

Comment: This seems to be the best method

Answer (score 3):

You could use a delayed expansion

```
forfiles /P "C:\temp" /M "st*.txt" /C "cmd /v:on /C set r=0x40 & echo !r:~0,1!relpath"
```

Or you can use percent expansion.

```
set percent=%
set at=@
forfiles /P "C:\temp" /M "st*.txt" /C "cmd /C echo %percent%at%percent%relpath"
```

Comment: Great approach! in the first option, if you omit the space after `set r=0x40` or if you enclose it in `()`, a simple expansion like `!r!` works as well...