# How to nest two `forfiles` loops properly (so that the inner body expands variables of both iteration levels)?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd, escaping, forfiles

I am trying to nest two `forfiles` loops so that the command of the inner loop receives `@` variables from both the outer and the inner loop iteration. For the latter the `@` variable replacement needs to be escaped for the outer loop so that the inner `forfiles` command receives the variable name.

I have got a code snippet that enumerates a given directory (`C:\root`), and if the iterated item is a directory on its own, all the contained text files (`*.txt`) are listed.
However, it does not work as expected: I tried to escape the expansion of `@file` with `\`, but it expands to the value of the outer loop:

```
2> nul forfiles /P "C:\root" /M "*" /C "cmd /C if @isdir==TRUE forfiles /P @path /M *.txt /C \"cmd /C echo @relpath -- \@file\""
```

Besides `\@file`, also `^@file`, `^^@file`, `^^^@file`, `0x40file` (`0x40` being the hexadecimal character code representation of `@`) expand to the value of the outer `forfiles` variable.
`\\@file` and `^^^^@file` expand to the outer value too, with `\` and `^` preceeded, respectively.
Even `@^file`, `@^^file` (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32403380/5047996)) does not work (the latter expands to `@file` literally).

So: is there a way to escape the replacement of `@` variables (like `@file`,...) from the outer `forfiles` loop so that the inner `forfiles` iteration receives the literal variable name and expands it to its value?

I am working on Windows 7 64-bit.

---

**Note:**
The `2> nul` redirection should avoid numerous error messages `ERROR: Files of type "*.txt" not found.` when no file in the currently processed directory matches the given mask (`*.txt`).

Comment: What's wrong with `for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir /b /S C:\root\*.txt') do echo %%A`?

Comment: @SomethingDark, of course there's nothing wrong using `for`; I'm just experimenting with `forfiles` and I'm wondering if there is a way to get the nested loops working...

Comment: Gotcha. Good luck; I have no idea how to answer your question, but now I'm curious, myself...

Comment: @SomethingDark, sometimes, `forfiles` has got advantages over `for`: 1) `forfiles` can return paths relative to the given root directory in `@relpath`, 2) `forfiles` returns also seconds of file times in `@ftime`, opposed to the `%~tI` expansion of `for %I`; to achive all that with `for` you need some extra code...

Comment: @Paul, I already tried to replace the `\"` in the inner `cmd /C` by `0x22`, but the result is just the same...

Comment: yes sorry, following the logics, every chars have to be escaped inside the second cmd, I have not seen `/` escaped

Comment: Thanks a lot vor down-voting without any comment!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to use the hexadecimal character code replacement feature of `forfiles` in the format `0xHH`, which can be nested on its own. In this context, `00x7840` is used, hence the first (outer) `forfiles` loop replaces the `0x78` portion by `x`, resulting in `0x40`, which is in turn resolved by the second (inner) `forfiles` loop by replacing it with `@`.

A simple `0x40` does *not* work as `forfiles` replaces hexadecimal codes in a first pass and *then* it handles the `@` variables in a second pass, so `0x40file` will be replaced by `@file` first and then expanded to the currently iterated item by the outer `forfiles` loop both.

---

The following command line walks through a given root directory and displays the relative path of each immediate sub-directory (iterated by the outer `forfiles` loop) and all text files found therein (iterated by the inner `forfiles` loop):

```
2> nul forfiles /P "C:\root" /M "*" /C "cmd /C if @isdir==TRUE forfiles /P @path /M *.txt /C 0x22cmd /C echo @relpath -- 00x7840file0x22"
```

The output might look like (relative sub-directory paths left, text files right):

> ```
> .\data_dir -- "text_msg.txt"
>
> .\logs_dir -- "log_book.txt"
> .\logs_dir -- "log_file.txt"
> ```

---

**Explanation of Code:**

- as described above, the `00x7840file` portion hides the `@file` variable name from the outer `forfiles` command and transfers its replacement to the inner `forfiles` command;
- to avoid any trouble with quotes `"` and `cmd /C`, quotes within the string after the `/C` switch of the outer `forfiles` are avoided by stating their hexadecimal code `0x22`;
  (`forfiles` supports escaping quotes like `\"`, however `cmd /C` does not care about the `\` and so it detects the `"`; `0x22` has no special meaning to `cmd` and so it is safe)
- the `if` statement checks whether the item enumerated by the outer `forfiles` loop is a directory and, if not, skips the inner `forfiles` loop;
- in case the enumerated sub-directory does not contain any items that match the given pattern, `forfiles` returns an error message like `ERROR: Files of type "*.txt" not found.` at STDERR; to avoid such messages, redirection `2> nul` has been applied;

---

**Step-by-Step Replacement:**

Here is the above command line again but with the redirection removed, just for demonstration:

```
forfiles /P "C:\root" /M "*" /C "cmd /C if @isdir==TRUE forfiles /P @path /M *.txt /C 0x22cmd /C echo @relpath -- 00x7840file0x22"
```

We will now extract the nested command lines which are going to be executed one after another.

Taking the items of the first line of the above sample output (`.\data_dir -- "text_msg.txt"`), the command line executed by the outer `forfiles` command is:

```
cmd /C if TRUE==TRUE forfiles /P "C:\root" /M *.txt /C "cmd /C echo ".\data_dir" -- 0x40file"
```

So the inner `forfiles` command line looks like (`cmd /C` removed, and the `if` condition is fulfilled):

```
forfiles /P "C:\root" /M *.txt /C "cmd /C echo ".\data_dir" -- 0x40file"
```

Now the command line executed by the inner `forfiles` command is (notice the removed literal quotes around `.\data_dir` and the instant replacement of `0x40file` by the value of variable `@file`):

```
cmd /C echo .\data_dir -- "text_msg.txt"
```

Walking though these steps from the innermost to the outermost command line like that, you could nest even more than two `forfiles` loops.

---

**Note:**

All path- or file-name-related `@`-variables are replaced by quoted strings each; however, the above shown sample output does not contain any surrounding quotes for the directory paths; this is because `forfiles` removes any literal (non-escaped) quotes `"` from the string after the `/C` switch; to get them back in the output here, replace `@relpath` in the command line by `00x7822@relpath00x7822`; `\\\"@relpath\\\"` works too (but is not recommended though to not confuse `cmd`).

---

#### Appendix:

Since `forfiles` is not an internal command, it should be possible to nest it without the `cmd /C` prefix, like `forfiles /C "forfiles /M *"`, for instance (unless any additional internal or external command, command concatenation, redirection or piping is used, where `cmd /C` is mandatory).
However, due to erroneous handling of command line arguments after the `/C` switch of `forfiles`, you actually need to state it like `forfiles /C "forfiles forfiles /M *"`, so the inner `forfiles` command doubled. Otherwise an error message (`ERROR: Invalid argument/option`) is thrown.
This best work-around has been found at this post: [forfiles without cmd /c](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26990159/5047996) (scroll to the bottom).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a workaround - forfiles is not a quick beast so any extra processing isn't going to matter much.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('2^>nul forfiles /P "C:\root" /M "*" /C "cmd /C if @isdir==TRUE echo @path"') do forfiles /P %%a /M *.txt /C "cmd /C echo @relpath -- @file"
pause
```